# SharePoint Online OneDrive Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document, onedrive

I have had a requirement if there is a way to display individual user one drive files on SharePoint front end page in a webpart? I haven't been able to see one OTTB?

I am trying to complete this with no code. Can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

OOTB there is no functionality that can do this. It would be possible with some development using the office graph and a custom web part.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no such OOB feature in SharePoint Online now. If you wan to display individual user's OneDrive files on SharePoint, you will need to do development work. Here is an example for you to check:https://www.tonyishere.co.uk/get-onedrive-recent-items-using-microsoft-graph-in-spfx/